# inline-blocks with width that amounts to 100% don't fit in one line

Tags: html, css

I want to have a div at the left side of a container, and a div on the right side of the container in the same line. I try to do so using inline-blocks, and text-align right for the right container.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbbBzE

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    I'm on the left
  </div>

  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="right">
      I'm on the right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



.container {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;  
}

.container > div {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%
}

.right-container {
  text-align: right;
}
```

For some reason, even though the parent container has font-size: 0, and the children are both 50%, they drop to the other line. Setting the width to 49% seems to work, but I don't understand why 50% doesn't when it should? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width also is affected by the border on the elements. You can add `box-sizing:border-box;` to those divs to make them sit side by side.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right-container {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">I'm on the left</div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="right">I'm on the right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```